# Why are RF transistors so expensive?

Tags: rf

I was looking around for RF power transistors expecting them to have around the same price as the IRFP250 and I noticed the immense price. A 160 watt UHF dual MOSFET was 70$. What characteristics make the high-frequency power transistors a lot more pricy then others?

Answer (score 2):

The main characteristic that make them higher price are the very low demand and small quantities purchased, compared to other transistors.

Comment: Also, anything that combines high power with high frequency is technically demanding to produce. In transistors, generally speaking, small sizes of the various regions promote high frequency operation: small bases in BJT's and so on, right? Case in point: we couldn't make a gigahertz CPU with big transistors. But small regions don't handle a lot of current. So large power handling together with small capacitances for high frequency operation probably requires some cunning.  (For very high power RF, vacuum tubes are still used, are they not?)

Comment: vaccum tubes arent any better. Seriously! $1000 dollars for 1 tube?